# Thread doesn't execute as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I wrote a simple multi thread program, but it does not running in the expected way.

```
public class LockTest {

    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @Test
    public void maintest(){
        System.out.println("main program");
        LockTest lockTest = new LockTest();
        Thread a = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("thread a");
                lockTest.process();
            }
        };

        Thread b = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("thread b");
                lockTest.process();
            }
        };

        a.start();
        b.start();
    }

    public void process(){
        System.out.println("start process");
        int i = 0;
        boolean result = false;
        do {
            i++;
            result = lock.tryLock();
            System.out.println(result + " " + i);
        }while (!result && i < 3);
        if (!result){
            System.out.println("get no lock");
            return;
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("get lock");
            System.out.println("process aaa");
            System.out.println("process bbb");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            System.out.println("process ddd");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
            System.out.println("release lock");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is not always the same. Sometimes only shows:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50858', transport: 'socket'
main program

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50858', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Or shows the result:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50935', transport: 'socket'
main program
thread b
thread a
start process
start process
false 1
true 1
get lock
process aaa
process bbb
false 2
false 3
get no lock
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50935', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why doesn't the program execute the whole code? Using IntelliJIdea with Java 8, JUnit test

Comment: Your question is unclear. What happened and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
a.join();
b.join();
```

after you start both treads.

It will wait until treads are finish.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50935', transport: 'socket'
```

Is printed when the java debugger is debugging a port of the JVM.

```
Disconnected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50935', transport: 'socket'
```

Is printed when the application has ended as the java debugger is no longer executing or simply put the application has ended.

Essentially, the application is sometimes finishing before the other threads receive CPU time. To ensure the *main* thread waits for the others to finish (meaning they receive CPU time to complete their respective `run()` methods), utilize the thread method `join()`. This causes the calling thread (in this case the *main* thread) to wait for the completion of that thread.

Multi-threading may yield different results because of the nature of multi-threading. Interrupts, swapping, resource allocations and much more determine when a thread executes and when it is waiting to have CPU time. Now remember, these waiting periods are on a microscopic level of time while the computer switches between executing threads.

If you are looking for the application to yield the same result every time it is run, you are looking for deterministic multi-threading and requires careful synchronizations and design to accomplish. If you are looking for logic to be run in the same *order* every time, you should not use multi-threading or else it will require overly complete conditions that negates the **power** of multi-threading.